# Using Legacy Library in Dot Net Standard with a call to Dot Net System.Drawing

Tags: c#, .net-standard

I am trying to migrate a library to Dot Net Standard 2.1 from Dot Net 4.7.2

I have a call to a 3rd party dll (written in Dot Net 4.7.2) that takes a System.Drawing.Image as a parameter

As the calling library is Dot Net Standard it uses System.Drawing.Common (The Dot Net standard version) so the call to the 3rd party library has a red squiggly under it stating:

```
Error CS7069 Reference to type 'Image' claims it is defined in 'System.Drawing', but it could not be found
```

I believe This is due to the mismatch between the Dot Net Standard version of System.Drawing and the Dot Net version.

So my question is simple...

**Can I reference the Dot Net version of System.Drawing in Dot Net Standard in order to get this call to work until the 3rd party releases an update that is compatible with Dot Net Standard?**

TIA

Comment: Have you tried using [windows compatibility pack](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/)?

Comment: I followed the instructions in the link, and installed the NuGet package, but no joy, is there something else I need to do?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Error CS7069 Reference to type 'Image' claims it is defined in 'System.Drawing', but it could not be found

Comment: I have a Dot Net Standard Bitmap, which I want to send to a legacy 3rd party library which expects a Dot net Bitmap

Comment: Can you create a minimal repro project somewhere?

Comment: Have you found the answer to your question yet? I'm in a similar situation.